# Deliver a copy of Scheduled SSRS Report to a backup file

Tags: file, reporting-services

I've seen this done but I'm not sure how to set it up. I need to place a copy of the scheduled report from SSRS into a file for backup. I need to be able to pull a report quickly when a clients email doesn't cooperate that day.  I'm not sure if you can schedule a report to deliver by email and to a file at the same time.

Comment: Why not .cc the email to another address setup to act like a repository? Or set up two jobs, one to email, one to file.

Answer (score 0):

Short of creating your own delivery extension, you can't have a subscription that delivers both via email and file share at the same time in SSRS.

Could you either:

- Just create two subscriptions - one that delivers to email, one that delivers to a network share.
- Have one subscription that delivers to a network share, and then another process that emails the file from the share?